# C# XML Element Prefix SOAP

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I have seen many SO answers but non seem to help with the issue I have.

What I am doing is calling a SOAP service from third party and it actually requires a prefix on element names.

Example:

```
<pref:test>test</pref:test>
```

I have created a client using Add service reference in VS.

I have a class which is where i want the prefix on each property.

```
public class WebsiteSoapHeader : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeader
{
    public WebsiteSoapHeader()
    {
        xmlns.Add("test", "https://xxx/service");
    }

    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    [XmlElement(ElementName ="test",Namespace = "https://xxx/service")]
    public string testprop { get; set; }
}
```

As this does not get serialized manually it only produces

```
<test xmlns="">test</test>
```

Comment: After doing some looking around there is nothing that does not require some kind of manual serialization.  If someone has done it using attributes then would be good to know more.